# Need a javascript to set height in given custom scenario

Tags: jquery

I have multple block level elements in one row with different height (based on the content inside).
How can I make same heigt for all the block level elements in one row (maximum height of the box should apply to all the other blocks in the row) through javascript.

Following is the JS Fiddle.. Want to make all the gray background boxes of each row with same height considering the maximum height of the box of that row:
http://jsfiddle.net/33PGQ/161/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .lp-box {
        display:inline-block;
        min-height:100px;
        margin:8px 10px 8px 0;
        padding:10px;
        width:245px;
        font: normal 16px Arial;
        vertical-align:top;
        background: #cacaca;
        }
        h4 {margin:10px;}
    </style>
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Accounting</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a  href="#">View Entries</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" >Definition Configuration</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Finance</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a  href="#">View Entries</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" >Definition Configuration</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>I.T.</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a  href="#">View Entries</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" >Definition Configuration</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">View Entries</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" >Definition Configuration</a></li> <li><a  href="#" >View Entries</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#" >Definition Configuration</a></li>                 
        </ul>
    </div>      
    <hr class="dotted" />
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Accounting</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Daily Activity</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>I.T.</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr class="dotted" />
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Daily Activity</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="lp-box">
    <h4>Misc.</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr class="dotted" />
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Accounting</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>Daily Activity</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="lp-box">
        <h4>I.T.</h4>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" >Abc</a></li>                   
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: So far didn't found any firm solution/logic, still trying
This is generated view source of java code. Due to urgent requirement, asked for help..

Comment: SO is not for making code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jquery `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function will let you loop through a list of elements. The simplest thing to try here would be to make two loops: 1 to get the maximum height of the elements, and the second to set them to that height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $(".lp-box");
    var height = 0;
    divs.each(function(index, el) {
        height = Math.max(height, $(el).height());
    });
    divs.each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).css("height", height+"px");
    });
});
```

If you are looking for each row, then I would recommend wrapping each row in a new `div` with a new class like `<div class="datarow"></div>`. Then the code could be modified as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.datarow").each(function(index, row) {
        var divs = $(row).find(".lp-box");
        var height = 0;
        divs.each(function(index, el) {
            height = Math.max(height, $(el).height());
        });
        divs.each(function(index, el) {
            $(el).css("height", height+"px");
        });
    });
});
```

If you do not want to make modifications to the HTML to accomplish this, it is still possible, albeit a little more complicated. I tested this in JSFiddle and it seems to be working. You will need to test it more thoroughly. This should work with your specific HTML example as the classes used must be the same, and the `hr` and `div` tags must both be direct children of the same parent.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get a unique list of all parents of code 
    // sections that contain the .lp-box elements.
    var parents = $(".lp-box").parent();

    //process for each code section
    parents.each(function(index, parent) {
        //create an empty array
        var rowdivs = [];

        $(parent).children().each(function(index, child) {
            var c = $(child);

            //see if we're at the HR tag
            if (c.hasClass("dotted")) {
                processRowHeights(rowdivs);

                //clear the array for the next row
                rowdivs = [];
            } else {
                //add to the array
                rowdivs.push(c);
            }
        });

        //pick up the last row
        if (rowdivs.length > 0) 
            processRowHeights(rowdivs);
    });
});

//process each element in the array
function processRowHeights(divArray) {
    var height = 0, divs = $(divArray);

    divs.each(function(index, el) {
        height = Math.max(height, $(el).height());
    });
    divs.each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).css("height", height+"px");
    });
}
```

Comment: That's working fine. But my requirement is more specific to each row ie.maximum height of box within each row. Rows are separeted by <hr class="dotted" />

Comment: That was super-fast. I am trying to find a way without modifying the code (as code is dynamic and its a big application with many such scenarios), like using <hr class="dotted"> as a seperator to break each loop. Thanks a lot for your quick assistance.

Comment: Somehow I knew you were going to say that... That is going to be a much more complicated algorithm. I'll see what I can do to help...

Comment: As one commentor said above, SO is not for people making code for you. However, tonight I am feeling generous, and your question posed an interesting challenge for me. It would be better for you to find this solution on your own. If you want some code quick to fix something, SO is generally not a good destination.

Comment: Totally agree. Henceforth, I will definitely take care of this. This was an urgent requirement which forced me to post this question. Sorry for this and thanks a ton for your timely help.

Comment: My requirement is there are only 4 boxes (maximum) in one row and all the boxes in single row should be of same height based on maximum height amoung them. I have tried but I think I am missing something.. Could you please help? Here's the jsfiddler of what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/33PGQ/164/